# Django MySQL charset setting is not working， utf8mb4 changed to utf8

Tags: mysql, django, docker

My setting file is looks like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        }
    },
}
```

After some migrates(like python manage.py migrate zero, python manage.py reset_db..), the MySql encoding changed from **utf8mb4** to **utf8**.

[image]

```bash
docker volume ls
docker volume rm -f xx    # this not work, say "xx volume is in use"

# use this one cleard the volume.
docker-compose -f xx.yml down --volumes
```

I use above command to recreate docker volumes fix it, But I wanna know why, so here is the question.

My docker-compose file looks like:

```yaml
# ...
services:
  # ...
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

While I asking this question, I try to look Django source code to find why, It's help me think more about my question, I try to reproduce this question，there are steps:

1. First the database was created by docker-compose, MySql's charset is utf8mb4.
2. Then execute "python manage.py migrate" to create tables.
3. I wanna merge the migrations to one, so I use these cmd to do it.

```bash
python manage.py migrage xx zero
rm xx/migrations/00*.py
python manage.py reset_db
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

4. I checked the cmd, db changing is from **python manage.py reset_db**.

So I goto find **reset_db** did what from [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions).

Here is the code:

```py
# file: management.commands.reset_db.py
# ...
connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
drop_query = 'DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `%s`' % database_name
utf8_support = '' if options['no_utf8_support'] else 'CHARACTER SET utf8'
create_query = 'CREATE DATABASE `%s` %s' % (database_name, utf8_support)
logging.info('Executing... "%s"', drop_query)
connection.query(drop_query)
logging.info('Executing... "%s"', create_query)
connection.query(create_query.strip())
# ...
```

reset_db first **drop database**, then **create database**.

I give the cmd one arg

```bash
python manage.py reset_db --no-utf8
```

then the database's encoding changed to **utf8mb4**.